# MyBatis is giving nullpointer exception when using isInCaseInsensitiveWhenPresent

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, ibatis

As per MyBatis document here https://mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/docs/conditions.html

*IsInCaseInsensitiveWhenPresent* should not render if a null value is passed.

So, below is my query:

```
 SelectStatementProvider selectStatement = select(allColumns())
                    .from(table1)
                    .where(table1.date1, isGreaterThanOrEqualToWhenPresent(from_))
                    .and(table1.date2, isLessThanWhenPresent(to_))
                    .and(table1.type, isInCaseInsensitiveWhenPresent(event))
                    .build()
                    .render(RenderingStrategies.MYBATIS3);
```

where *event* is input which is *Collection* type.

Here, query render fails if *event* is null. So, any suggestions? I want search a column whether its having a value from list of values and should be case-insensitive.

Comment: That condition expects a non-null list - the condition won't render if the list is empty. I understand this is different than the other conditions. For now you could do something like `event == null ? Collections.emptyList() : event`. I will make this part of the code in the next release.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-dynamic-sql/pull/346

Comment: Rajeev, there you just got a fix from Jeff Butler himself.